# Como inserir o id gerado no insert como chave estrangeira de outra tabela?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

```html
<?php
      include_once "./Models/Usuario.php";
      include_once './Models/Login.php';
      include_once './Models/Profissional.php';
      include_once './Models/Cabecalho.php'; 
      include_once './Models/Teste.php'; 

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link href="./semantic/js/dropdown.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="./semantic/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet">
     
     <title> cabecalho de cabecalho </title>
 </head>
<body>



<?php

@$usuario = new Login();
@$cod_usuario = $usuario->retorna_codigo_usuario();

@$user = new Login();
@$in_user=$user->taLogado();
@$tipo_user = $user->retorna_tipo();
 if ($in_user == false){ 
    header('location:?pgs=inicial');
} 



  if ($tipo_user == 2 ) {
?>
<div class="ui stackable centered grid">
  <div class="ui eight wide column">
  <h2 class="ui horizontal divider header">
    <div class="content">
      Cadastrar novo cabeçalho
    </div>
    </h2>
   <form class="ui form" method="POST" name="nr_ficha" action="./Controllers/processa_cab_teste.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="ui stacked secondary segment">
            <div class="three fields">
              <div class="field">
                <label>Código do produto</label>
                <input type="text" name="cod_produto_cabecalho" placeholder="Exemplo: D21" required value="<?= @$_SESSION['dados_cabecalho']['cod_produto_cabecalho']; ?>">
              </div>
              <div class="five wide field">
                <label>Data</label>
                <input type="date" name="data_cabecalho" placeholder="Exemplo: " required value="<?= @$_SESSION['dados_cabecalho']['data_cabecalho']; ?>">
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <label>Hora</label>
                <input type="time" name="hora_cabecalho" required value="<?= @$_SESSION['dados_cabecalho']['hora_cabecalho']; ?>">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="two fields">
              <div class="field">
                <label>Responsável</label>
                <input type="text" name="responsavel_cabecalho" placeholder="Exemplo: Ana" required value="<?= @$_SESSION['dados_cabecalho']['responsavel_cabecalho']; ?>">
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <label>Total testado</label>
                <input type="text" name="qtd_cabecalho" placeholder="Exemplo: 340" required value="<?= @$_SESSION['dados_cabecalho']['qtd_cabecalho']; ?>">
              </div>
            </div>
              <p></p>
          <input type="hidden" name="cod_cabecalho_profissional" value='<?=$cod_usuario; ?>' method="POST">
            <button type="submit" name="nr_ficha" class="ui fluid large grey submit button" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">Continuar
            </button>
       </form>
      </div>
        </div>
  <?php }
  else{
   echo "";
  }

  



?>
   
  </div>
</div>




</body>
</html>
































<?php
      include_once "./Models/Usuario.php";
      include_once './Models/Login.php';
      include_once './Models/Profissional.php';
      include_once './Models/Teste.php'; 
      include_once './Models/Cabecalho.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link href="./semantic/js/dropdown.js" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="./semantic/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <title> Cadastro de teste </title>
  </head>
<body>



<?php


@$usuario = new Login();
@$cod_usuario = $usuario->retorna_codigo_usuario();

@$user = new Login();
@$in_user=$user->taLogado();
@$tipo_user = $user->retorna_tipo();
  if ($in_user == false){ 
    header('location:?pgs=inicial');
} 


$cabecalho = new Cabecalho();
$nr_ficha = $cabecalho->busca_cabecalho();

          

    if ($tipo_user == 2 ) {?>
<div class="ui stackable centered grid">
  <div class="ui eight wide column">
  <h2 class="ui horizontal divider header">
    <div class="content">
      Cadastrar novo teste
    </div>
    </h2>
      <form class="ui form" method="POST" action="./Controllers/processa_testeq.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="ui stacked secondary segment">
          <div class="two fields">
            <div class="field">
              <label>Refugo</label>
              <input type="text" name="cod_refugo_teste" required>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <label>Quantidade</label>
              <input type="text" name="qtd_refugo" required>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
            <p></p>
            <input type="hidden" name="nr_ficha_teste"  value='<?='$nr_ficha'; ?>'>
          <input type="hidden" name="cod_usuario_profissional" value='<?=$cod_usuario; ?>' method="POST">
            <button type="submit" name="" class="ui fluid large grey submit button">Continuar</button>
          </form>
      </div>
        </div>
    <?php }else{
      echo "";
    }
?>
   
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php

require "../Models/Cabecalho.php";
require "../Models/Profissional.php";


$data_cabecalho = date($_POST['data_cabecalho']);
$responsavel_cabecalho = $_POST['responsavel_cabecalho'];
$qtd_cabecalho = $_POST['qtd_cabecalho'];
$hora_cabecalho = $_POST['hora_cabecalho'];
$cod_produto_cabecalho  = $_POST['cod_produto_cabecalho'];
$codigo = $_POST['cod_cabecalho_profissional'];
$nr_ficha = $_GET['nr_ficha'];
     
 $cabecalho = new Cabecalho();
 $cabecalho->cadastrar_cabecalho($data_cabecalho, $responsavel_cabecalho, $qtd_cabecalho, $hora_cabecalho, $cod_produto_cabecalho, $codigo);
 header("location:../?pgs=form_testeq");
  
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
<?php

require "../Models/Teste.php";
require "../Models/Profissional.php";


$cod_refugo_teste = $_POST['cod_refugo_teste'];
$nr_ficha_teste = $_POST['nr_ficha_teste'];
$qtd_refugo = $_POST['qtd_refugo'];
$codigo = $_POST['cod_usuario_profissional'];
$valoresrefugos = explode(",",$cod_refugo_teste);
$valoresqtds = explode(",",$qtd_refugo);


$unir = 'INSERT INTO teste (cod_refugo_teste, qtd_refugo) VALUES (';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($valoresrefugos); $i++) {
 if ($i == count($valoresrefugos) - 1) {
  $unir .= "'" . $valoresrefugos[$i] . "','" . $valoresqtds[$i] . "')";
 }
 else {
  $unir .= "'" . $valoresrefugos[$i] . "','" . $valoresqtds[$i] . "'), (";
 }
}


   
if (is_numeric($codigo)){   
 $teste = new Teste();
 $teste->cadastrar_teste($cod_refugo_teste, $qtd_refugo, $nr_ficha_teste, $codigo);
 header("location:../?pgs=modal_cadastro_teste");
  }else{
   echo "Erro!";
  }
```

Quero adicionar a chave primária de uma tabela em uma chave estrangeira de outra tabela. A chave primária da tabela1 é auto incremento, e na hora de passar para a segunda tabela, o valor aparece nulo. Como faço por meio do banco de dados essa ação?

Obs: A chave primária da primeira tabela (cab_teste) é nr_ficha, que não está ali por ser autoincremento. E a chave estrangeira da tabela teste é nr_ficha_teste.

```
public function cadastrar_cabecalho($data_cabecalho, $responsavel_cabecalho, $qtd_cabecalho, $hora_cabecalho, $cod_produto_cabecalho, $codigo_profissional){
    $conexao = Database::getConnection();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO cab_teste (data_cabecalho, responsavel_cabecalho, qtd_cabecalho, hora_cabecalho, cod_produto_cabecalho, cod_cabecalho_profissional)
            VALUES ('$data_cabecalho', '$responsavel_cabecalho', '$qtd_cabecalho', '$hora_cabecalho', '$cod_produto_cabecalho', '$codigo_profissional');";

    $conexao->exec($sql);
}

public function cadastrar_teste($cod_refugo_teste, $qtd_refugo, $nr_ficha_teste, $codigo_profissional){

    $conexao = Database::getConnection();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO teste (cod_refugo_teste, qtd_refugo, nr_ficha_teste, cod_usuario_profissional)
            VALUES ('$cod_refugo_teste', '$qtd_refugo', '$nr_ficha_teste', '$codigo_profissional');";

    $conexao->exec($sql);
}
```

Comment: Qual é a chave primária? Qual é a chave estrangeira? Como passou o valor? Como obteve o id que foi gerado no *insert*? E, por último, nada aqui é urgente - a menos que alguém esteja morrendo, aí abrimos uma exceção :D

Comment: Coloquei como observação as duas primeiras perguntas. O resto eu não sei responder porque é justamente na hora de puxar o valor que eu me perco.

Comment: Coloque o código onde você chama os métodos `cadastrar_cabecalho` e `cadastrar_teste`.

Answer (score 2):

No `PHP` existe uma função especifica para pegar o último ID inserido.

**MySQLi**

Se estiver utilizado `MySQLi` pode utilizar o modo procedural ou o modo OO.

*Modo Procedural*

```
mysqli_insert_id($conexao);
```

*Modo OO*

```
$conexao->insert_id;
```

**PDO**

Se estiver utilizado `PDO` pode utilizar da seguinte forma:

```
$conexao->lastInsertId();
```

**Solução para você**

No seu caso, você pode alterar a função `cadastrar_cabecalho` para que retorne o `ID` cadastrado (como mostrado em baixo). Com isso basta pegar o `ID` retornado e passar na função `cadastrar_teste`.

```
public function cadastrar_cabecalho($data_cabecalho, $responsavel_cabecalho, $qtd_cabecalho, $hora_cabecalho, $cod_produto_cabecalho, $codigo_profissional){
    $conexao = Database::getConnection();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO cab_teste (data_cabecalho, responsavel_cabecalho, qtd_cabecalho, hora_cabecalho, cod_produto_cabecalho, cod_cabecalho_profissional)
            VALUES ('$data_cabecalho', '$responsavel_cabecalho', '$qtd_cabecalho', '$hora_cabecalho', '$cod_produto_cabecalho', '$codigo_profissional');";

    $conexao->exec($sql);
    return mysqli_insert_id($conexao);
}
```

Comment: De qualquer forma, assim que o formulário do cadastro de teste processa os dados, esse erro aparece:

Notice: Undefined variable: nr_ficha_teste in C:\xampp\htdocs\TESTE_BANCADA\Controllers\processa_testeq.php on line 29

Comment: E logo depois aparece um fatal error dizendo que não posso adicionar ou deletar nenhum valor dentro de nr_ficha_teste

Comment: como está fazendo a chamada dos métodos agora?